# How to create customized slides or how to mimick powerpoints masterlayout

Tags: r, r-markdown, slideshow, quarto

I wonder how can I create customized slides with quarto:
Each slide should look like this:

[image]

I have tried:

to do like this:
https://quarto.org/docs/presentations/powerpoint.html

Creating a Template

To create a template from scratch, start with the default PowerPoint template as follows:

`quarto pandoc -o template.pptx --print-default-data-file reference.pptx`

Then edit the template.pptx file within PowerPoint as desired, and use it as the value for reference-doc (as shown above) when rendering your slides:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to apply a template to a presentation by simply adding the `reference-doc`, for example: https://www.meyerperin.com/using-quarto/#powerpoint-templates

Note that the template has to have the layouts that Pandoc/Quarto expects:
https://www.meyerperin.com/using-quarto/#powerpoint-layout-rules